# Detecting when a DLL has raised an exception

Tags: c#, exception, mfc

OK, so I have the C# DLL method:

```
   public void DeletePublisher(string strName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_PublisherData.PublisherDictionary.ContainsKey(strName))
                _PublisherData.PublisherDictionary.Remove(strName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SimpleLog.Log(ex);
            
        }
    }
```

It works fine. If there is a exception it is detected and added to the log.

At the moment, the above is called via MFC in my C++ project using a wrapper:

```
bool CMSATools::DeletePublisher(CString strPublisher)
{
    bool bDeleted = false;

    if (m_pInterface != nullptr)
    {
        CComBSTR bstrPublisher = strPublisher.AllocSysString();

        throw_if_fail(m_pInterface->DeletePublisher(bstrPublisher));

        bDeleted = true;
    }

    return bDeleted;
}
```

They both work fine. The issue is that fact that the CPP method currently has no knowledge of the C# method having failed. Now, in this particular instance I know I could change the signature of the DLL method to return false for a exception failure occurring and examine that return value in the CPP file.

But, in other instances I am already using the return value and thus, it would seem for consistency to me, that I pass in a `bool bExceptionRaised` parameter instead to my methods in the DLL.

That way, I can test that value when the method seemed to complete and if it is false act accordingly.

At the moment my application doesn't realise that an exception occurred and that is confusion.

Can I assume that either of these methodologies are the simplest approach to what I am trying to detect?

## Update

Based on the answer provided I have tried to follow this [tutorial](http://xmight.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/cli-bridge-to-connect-c-project-to-csharp.html) and I am getting confused. I have tried to follow it and I can't create a CLR DLL and build it that is a bridge to my C# DLL file.

Whilst I appreciate the answer I feel like it is breaking up everything I have worked on since the C# DLL already handles and logs it's exceptions. Whilst I would like to learn how to build this bridge for the future, I still think perhaps at the point in time just changing my signatures is sufficient. Either way, my attempt a basic build of a bridge is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a C++/CLI wrapper for the access of the managed component.

With C++/CLI you can directly use the C# component can catch the managed exception and you can throw a native exception or even return true or false... whatever you want.

```
void DoManagedStuff(SOMEDATA somedata)
{
    try
    {
        auto sm = ConvertToSomeDataToManaged(somedata);
        CallManagedCode(sm);
    }
    catch (Exception^ e)
    {
        throw CMyNativeException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I do not know how to do this.

Comment: Compile a part of your program with /CLR or use a separate DLL that uses /CLR (I prefer this) and use all your C# stuff there. Thre is a bunch of code in the internet how this can be done. I never use .NET components with COM.

Comment: I am sorry but I am getting lost with this. I will update my question.

Comment: I am looking at this again. Could you please show me a example of `CMyNativeException` in it's basic form? Thanks.

Comment: The other problem I seem to have here is I can't work out how to call the C++/CLI wrapper correctly from unmanaged code.

Comment: You can use any native exception. Either MFC exceptions or your own classes. The C++/CLI wrapper is just a function that is defined in the in a modul that is compiled with /clr. So compile a file with /clr declare and define your function as usual.